# Show image when its downloaded in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

I have a question about downloading images and view them in a UITableViewCell.

Expose the flow:

I login to the app.

If the login is valid, it asks a server API that returns me a JSON data users in which there is a picture ID.

We request the image back to the API by sending the ID of the image using dispantch_async.
This information and the image is stored in a NSObject which is stored in a NSMutableArray.

While the images are being downloaded the application passes to a second UITableViewController, which has a custom UITableViewCell with image

The problem is here, when it appears, the images are blank, that have not yet been charged. When I RefreshData, displaying properly, since they have already been loaded.

Question: Is there a way to do that images are recharged when they are downloaded? No matter one by one or all at once.

Unfortunately, perform the request of the image on the Cell, is not possible, since these images are used in multiple tables of the application and want to load them once.

I am open to other solutions to mine.

thank you very much

Greetings.

EDIT some pieces of code.

Code that calls the downloader in User :NSObject

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    aux1.imageProfileUrn  = ([itemDic valueForKey:@"imageProfileUrn"] == (id)[NSNull null])? nil : [Imagen getImagenPerfil:[itemDic objectForKey:@"appId"]];;
});
```

@implementation Imagen
+ (UIImage *) getImagenPerfil: (NSString *) appID {

```
UIImage *image;

NSString *cadenaCreacion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"appID=%@",appID];

NSData *postData = [cadenaCreacion dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?action=getImagenPerfil",urlApi]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:100];


NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"imagen: %@, appid: %@", requestReply, appID);
image = [UIImage imageWithData:requestHandler];
return image;
```

}

this is the image downloader for each user.

Then in table only assign the user image to the UIImageView

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SO. Please consider adding some relevant code to further improve your question.

Comment: Try to reload the table after the async call returns to the main queue.

Comment: Use SDWebImage: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage -- It will handle all of this for you.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier added some code.

Comment: @improgrammer how I can call a reload to the table, which is in other section of the app?

Comment: @Logan I've investigated the SDWebImage but it's not that i require. This calls the image download in the TableCell, but in my app, the image download it's called on an NSObject, and then, the cell uses this image

Answer (score 0):

First of All Add SDWebImage Library...

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

& then in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //Write 
  [cell.Img_thumb sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your URl for Image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

**///----------------------Second Method-------------------------//**

@carlos, Try this one... in Parameters send url & saving file name.

```
-(void) Download_Video :(NSString *)videoUrl tag:(NSString *)filename
{
    //download the file in a seperate thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
        NSString *urlToDownload = videoUrl;
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Download/%@.mp4", documentsDirectory,filename];

            //saving is done on main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"File Saved !");

                [self.tblMain reloadData];
                UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Download Completed" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [Alert show];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

***& IN TABLEVIEW METHOD   USE BELOW CODE,...***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString  *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Download/%@.mp4", documentsDirectory,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
    if (fileExists)
    {
        [cell.Btn_Download setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.Btn_Download setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mehul, as i said, I can't load the image on the cell. It is loaded on the NSObject and the cell gets the image from it. I need to download in the object and then, when it's downloaded, charge it on the table cell image

Comment: Hi Mehul, the object load function is called on Login function, so there is no table on it. Cannot use [self.tblMain reloadData];

Comment: @CarlosMelgarejo, So for Set image,what you have use There ?

Comment: First, I call the image download on the NSObject, while I show the table which needs to show. Then, I want to load the image. I cant download it, because it's a forum post, so download every post the user image it's not good. I save the user image on the user object to reuse it on all the posts

Comment: @CarlosMelgarejo, i think you need expert advice..i have solve it with very simple way plz use this frd. why you try to do it difficult .